# powershell, search a filename for 5 characters after the second. create a new directory if it is unique, and move, if not, just move

Tags: powershell

I am very very new to powershell, and have managed to get some basic commands to run. However, i am stuck on this one.

I have a folder with hundreds of .txt files in them. Each .txt file has a specific naming format.
220401.tailnm.22JUN21.CALLSIGN.txt
I need to be able to break these files out by month and year.

So how can I write:
look at all of the text files, search each filename for the first 5 characters after the second "."
If that directory doesn't exist, create a new one with that name and move the file into it.
if the directory already exists, just move the file into it.
??

I have found some similar posts online, but I don't fully understand what they are doing, hence why what i have come up with probably doesn't make much sense?

`$files = get-childitem  {$_.name -like "011529.tailnm.*"} $files  %{$date = $_.name.Split('.')[2] | if (-not(test-path $date)) {md $date} $_.fullname | move -destination $date}`

I just keep getting the red error:
Get-ChildItem : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Filter'.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance,
Kind Regards

Comment: `$files = Get-ChildItem -Path 'X:\TheRootFolder' -Filter "*.tailnm.*.txt" -File`

Comment: Hi @Theo, thank you, but as i am new to this i don't know if i have used that in the correct way. it runs without errors, but does absolutely nothing!
```$files = get-childitem -path 'C:\users\xxxxxxx' -Filter "*.tailnm.*.txt" -file | %{$date = $_.name.Split('.')[2] | if (-not(test-path $date)) {md $date} $_.fullname | move -destination $date}```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this should do what you want. I have added inline comments on every step to help understand the code.

```
# specify the rootfolder for the subdirectories and files
$destination = 'X:\The folder where the subfolders should be and the files to be moved to'
# find the files that fit the naming format
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\users\xxxxxxx' -Filter "*.tailnm.*.txt" -File | ForEach-Object {
    $date = $_.Name.Split('.')[2]
    if ($date.Length -gt 5) { $date = $date.Substring(0,5) }
    # combine the target destination folder path
    $targetDirectory = Join-Path -Path $destination -ChildPath $date
    if (-not(Test-Path -Path $targetDirectory -PathType Container)) {
        # create the subfolder if it did not yet exist
        $null = New-Item -Path $targetDirectory -ItemType Directory
    }
    # finaly move the file (represented by $_)
    $_ | Move-Item -Destination $targetDirectory
}
```

Comment: Hi Theo, that is fantastic. and thank you for the explanations as well. that has really helped. One last question, but I don't know if it is possible.  the $date field is now 7 characters long, do you know if there is a way to split it to only use the first 5 characters after the second '.'?

Comment: In fact, I have found a solution. please let me know if this is what you would do?

```$destination = 'C:\Users\xxxx'
get-childitem -path 'C:\Users\xxxx\' -filter "*.tailnm.*.txt" -file | foreach-object {$date = $_.name.substring(14,5)
$targetdirectory = join-path -path $destination -childpath $date
if (-not(test-path -path $targetdirectory -pathtype container)) {
$null = new-item -path $targetdirectory -itemtype directory
}
$_ | move-item -destination $targetdirectory
}```

Comment: @Tjones Thanks for the nice feedback. I have added this line `if ($date.Length -gt 5) { $date = $date.Substring(0,5) }` to the code. This is safer than your solution `$_.name.substring(14,5)`, because if the name of the file is less than that, an error will occur.